# “Aquathlon” in Classical Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, word-request

> An aquathlon is a multisport race consisting of continuous run and swim elements. Competitors complete a swim immediately followed by a run over various distances.

How would this race be named in Latin? I don’t know if it was a thing in Antiquity, or if one need to use “cursus xxx”.

Answer (score 3):

„Aquathlon“ is a modern formation from Latin aqua “water” and athlon (<Gr. ἆθλον) “contest”. One could Latinize it as “athlon aquaticum”.

Answer (score 3):

The usual Latin word for this type of contest is [*certamen*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcertamen). For example, the contest between Homer and Hesiod was known as the *Certamen*, and Nero [instituted](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Suetonius/12Caesars/Nero*.html#12) the *Neronia*, a *quinquinnale certamen* for music, gymnastics, and horse riding. Horse races could also be called *certamina*.

There are a number of different works for "aquatic", such as *aquaticum*, *aquale*, *aquarium*, and even *aquatile*. They are all more or less equal. I don't believe the Romans ever had aquatic games, so there's no telling for sure which one would be picked, but *aquaticum* and *aquatile* are both used to refer to water-dwelling animals, while *aquale* and *aquarium* are more commonly used as substantives for other water-related activities (an *aqualis*, for example, is a washing basin, while an *aquarius* could be a water-pipe inspector).